# How can I fix this error (Java Method + Array)?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make a program which, after filling an array in `main()`, through a method, returns the arithmetic mean of the elements contained in that array.

When I call the method to execute the process (the line where I use the `System.out.print`) it gives me an error, saying that the method is not applicable for the arguments in it. But it should lead to an array of `int`s.

**Code**

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class MainClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {        
            System.out.println(meanArray (2, 6, 9, 19, 1));
        }

        static int meanArray (int [] a) {
            Scanner inputLine = new Scanner(System.in);

            int numbers;
            int start;
            int sum = 0;
            int mean;

            numbers = inputLine.nextInt();

            for (start = 0; start < numbers; start++) {
                a[start] = inputLine.nextInt();
                sum = sum + a[start];
            }

            mean = sum/numbers;

            return mean;    
        }

}
```

Comment: You had better define `mean` as `double` or `float`,Also the way you define an array is incorrect

Comment: So how should I declare it in order to do fill it correctly?

Comment: The answers below will help you solve your *immediate* problem, however there's something wrong with the overall logic of your program: you want to pass in an int array loaded with data, just to overwrite it in the function. That's a rather strange thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
System.out.println (meanArray (2, 6, 9, 19, 1));
```

it expected a method with a signature like

```
public static Something meanArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
```

Most likely what you intended was

```
public static Something meanArray(int... a) {
```

which accepts a variable number of arguments.

Comment: I tried and it actually fixes the error, however when I execute the program, the console results empty, when it should return the arithmetic mean of 2, 6 etc.
Might there be an error even later in the code for which it doesn't work?

Comment: @Toge Your program expects to read the values from the console and ignores the values you provide.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: My program should fill the array with the values I give to it in Main and, with the method, return me the arith. mean of the values in the array when i run it, so yea, I think that's what I intended

Comment: @Toge If you don't need to read from the console, I suggest you remove the code which uses the Scanner.

Comment: With a couple of changes, it works perfectly now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Toge Your last problem is that you should return a `double` e.g. `2/3 == 0` in integer arithmetic.

Comment: Ye I know, I will have to expand the program later so that it returns how many values there are in the array lower than the arithmetic mean, so I put it as an int intentionally cause the final return won't be the mean but a quantity of elements (int), thanks anyway c:

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this code is you create a method that take an integer array as parameter and you send different integer values but not an integer array when calling the method. Instead calling;

```
meanArray(1,2,4,3)
```

you should declare integer array and pass the variable to the method.
It will be better to declare array variable first and pass it to the function like:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4};
meanArray(a);
```

And you donot need to declare another numbers variable ( lenth is inbuilt function to return size of an array)inside the method for summing elements of array, try as follows inside the meanArray();

```
for(start=0;start<a.length;start++){
sum+=a[start];
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. You have to give same input to the numbers variable inside method to the size of array you had passed from main method

Comment: It can't work. And in fact it doesn't compile. That's not how you declare an array. Always test.

Comment: I’m sorry, i have posted another solution if previous one not works .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the numbers in your code, declare and initialize the array with: 
`int[] array ={2,6,9,19,1};`  and then call `meanArray(array);`

If you want to test an arbitrary set of numbers from console, you need to declare the array differently with: 
`int[] array = new int[5];`     //*5 states how many numbers you will input from console *

and then you need to change the loop interval to: `start < array.length;`